# What's the cause/impact of this Hibernate Search error?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

We recently upgraded from Java 8 to 11 which may or may not be related to this new error we've started seeing.  We kept Hibernate-Search at `5.10.6.Final` b/c upgrading seems like a big undertaking, but Spring is managing a lot of the other dependencies now, including:
`Hibernate-Core 5.4.20.Final`, `Elasticsearch Client 6.6.2`, `Apache HTTP client 4.5.12`, and `Apache HTTP core 4.4.13`.

Started sporadically seeing:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented! Expected to produce content only over produceContent(), or writeTo(OutputStream) if blocking calls are acceptable for your use case.
    at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.util.impl.GsonHttpEntity.getContent(GsonHttpEntity.java:164)
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.es.restclient.ElasticsearchRestClientInstrumentationHelperImpl.createClientSpan(ElasticsearchRestClientInstrumentationHelperImpl.java:103)
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.es.restclient.ElasticsearchRestClientInstrumentationHelperImpl.createClientSpan(ElasticsearchRestClientInstrumentationHelperImpl.java:48)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequestAsync(RestClient.java:250)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequestAsync(RestClient.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.client.impl.DefaultElasticsearchClient.send(DefaultElasticsearchClient.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.client.impl.DefaultElasticsearchClient.lambda$submit$0(DefaultElasticsearchClient.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.search.util.impl.Futures.lambda$create$0(Futures.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniComposeStage(CompletableFuture.java:995)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:2137)
    at org.hibernate.search.util.impl.Futures.create(Futures.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.client.impl.DefaultElasticsearchClient.submit(DefaultElasticsearchClient.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.work.impl.SimpleElasticsearchWork.lambda$execute$1(SimpleElasticsearchWork.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniComposeStage(CompletableFuture.java:995)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:2137)
    at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.work.impl.SimpleElasticsearchWork.execute(SimpleElasticsearchWork.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.processor.impl.ElasticsearchWorkProcessor.start(ElasticsearchWorkProcessor.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.processor.impl.ElasticsearchWorkProcessor.executeAsyncUnsafe(ElasticsearchWorkProcessor.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.processor.impl.ElasticsearchWorkProcessor.executeSyncUnsafe(ElasticsearchWorkProcessor.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.query.impl.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.query.impl.ElasticsearchHSQueryImpl.execute(ElasticsearchHSQueryImpl.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.query.impl.ElasticsearchHSQueryImpl.queryEntityInfos(ElasticsearchHSQueryImpl.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.FullTextQueryImpl.doHibernateSearchList(FullTextQueryImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.FullTextQueryImpl.list(FullTextQueryImpl.java:225)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.FullTextQueryImpl.getResultList(FullTextQueryImpl.java:124)
    at com.bottomline.dm.core.service.AbstractDmHibernateSearchService.search(AbstractDmHibernateSearchService.java:64)
    at com.bottomline.dm.core.service.matching.DefaultDedupingService.findProbableDupeIds(DefaultDedupingService.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy256.findProbableDupeIds(Unknown Source)
    at com.bottomline.dm.batch.job.segmentation.dedupe.DedupeSubStep.findProbableDupes(DedupeSubStep.java:328)
    at com.bottomline.dm.batch.job.segmentation.dedupe.DedupeSubStep.doFindDupeSets(DedupeSubStep.java:180)
    at com.bottomline.dm.batch.job.segmentation.dedupe.DedupeSubStep.execute(DedupeSubStep.java:110)
    at com.bottomline.dm.batch.job.segmentation.dedupe.DedupeSubStep$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ef3c77a2.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at com.bottomline.dm.batch.job.segmentation.dedupe.DedupeSubStep$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e46d85b9.execute(<generated>)
    at com.bottomline.common.core.springframework.batch.step.SubStepsTasklet.executeSubStep(SubStepsTasklet.java:119)
    at com.bottomline.common.core.springframework.batch.step.SubStepsTasklet.execute(SubStepsTasklet.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy259.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:68)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:68)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:137)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:774)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3c6ee530.doExecute(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:319)
    at com.bottomline.common.core.springframework.batch.security.SecureJob.execute(SecureJob.java:65)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:147)
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.impl.async.SpanInScopeRunnableWrapper.run(SpanInScopeRunnableWrapper.java:64)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Can anyone explain why this exception occurs (seemingly randomly) and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

That method should never be called, and in fact it's never called in all the Hibernate Search integration tests.

Two possible explanations:

1. Your payload, configuration or setup somehow leads the Elasticsearch REST client or Apache HTTP client to try to serialize data in an unusual way (calling this method instead of the usual one).
2. You are using a different version of the Elasticsearch REST client or Apache HTTP client than the one that Hibernate Search expects. For reference, Hibernate Search `5.10.6.Final` expects ES Rest client `5.6.8` and Apache HTTP client `4.5.2`. All the versions are listed [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-search-parent/5.10.6.Final/pom).

I'd be inclined to say that you're in the first case, and this `co.elastic.apm.agent.es.restclient.ElasticsearchRestClientInstrumentationHelperImpl` class is to blame, as I don't see it anywhere in a normal Hibernate Search setup. You probably added that yourself?

**EDIT:** for what it's worth, in the next version of Hibernate Search 6.0 `GsonHttpEntity` will implement `getContent()`, because it was needed for something else. You probably know the deal, though: Hibernate Search 6 brings new cool features, but is in Beta (though the very late stages of Beta) and exposes a different API. [More info](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/6.0/#whats-new).

Comment: Our org.elasticsearch.client is at 6.6.2, Apache HTTP client is at 4.5.12, and Apache HTTP core is at 4.4.13.  Sounds like this could be the problem?

Comment: Possibly. Though I still wonder where this `ElasticsearchRestClientInstrumentationHelperImpl` comes from.

Comment: To answer your question: "_You probably added that yourself?_"  No, we didn't explicitly add `ElasticsearchRestClientInstrumentationHelperImpl` or that package.  I'm not sure where its coming from or why `performRequestAsync` would be calling into it.